# java command line errors

Tags: java, command-line

I'm new to java and I'm trying to compile and run a web service example from a book.
The example uses 3 files.
I can create an Eclipse Project and Run it. It works fine this way.

From the command line I tried

**javac TimeServer.java TimeServerImpl.java TimeServerPublisher.java**

And got no errors

This program does not run on the command line returns error:

"Could not find the main class"

**java TimeServerPublisher**

running using the -classpath option returns the same result.
Set classpath does not help either. ie

**java -classpath . TimeServerPublisher**

fails as well

Most of the online docs specify I need a classpath. I tried everything they suggested.

Please Help. Thanks in advance

Source:

TimeServer.java

```
package ch01.ts;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) // more on this later
public interface TimeServer
{
    @WebMethod String getTimeAsString();
    @WebMethod long getTimeAsElapsed();
}
```

TimeServerImpl.java

```
package ch01.ts;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "ch01.ts.TimeServer")

public class TimeServerImpl implements TimeServer
{

@Override
public String getTimeAsString()
{ 
    return new Date().toString();
}

@Override
public long getTimeAsElapsed()
{ 
    return new Date().getTime(); 
}
```

TimeServerPublisher.java

```
package ch01.ts;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class TimeServerPublisher
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is not named `TimeServerPublisher`; it's named `ch01.ts.TimeServerPublisher`. Even if you manage to get the JVM to find your class file, it will reject it with a wrong-name error, as you must invoke the class with its full name.

Put all the class files into a directory `ch01/ts` if they're not there already, and from ch01's parent directory, type

```
java -cp . ch01.ts.TimeServerPublisher
```

I guarantee that done correctly this will work.

Comment: Thanks so much! ... I was going nuts trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the package statements until you know how they work. to have that package, your sources and binaries should be under ./ch01/ts/ and you would compile and invoke as:

```
javac ch01/ts/*.java
java ch01.ts.TimeServerPublisher
```

Answer (score 1):

Move all your class files to folder `ch01/ts`.

and then execute command

```
java ch01.ts.TimeServerPublisher
```

There you go. If you say `javac -d ch01/ts *.java` during compilation, it will be solved.